# Java-6 tag needs updating

Tags: discussion, tags

I think the [java-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-6) excerpt is outdated and should be removed/replaced. Asking here because I'm not certain, and I don't know what to replace it with. Here's what it says currently (created April 2011):

> Java SE version 6 was released in December 2006, and given the long length of time until Java SE 7 was released (July 2011) it will likely be the dominant version of Java for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not much of a fan of version-specific tags, but you know, there *might* be some poor soul that has to support a Java 6 project out there.

Hopefully this description will suit them better:

> Java SE version 6 was released in December 2006. Use this tag for questions specific to this version of Java.

Nothing else in the original outside of the release date (even that I'm a bit iffy about) should be in an excerpt.  But this gives us a base to build from.

Comment: "I'm not much of a fan of version-specific tags" finally, I found a kindred soul.